# can't start session for user's

Tags: php, session, logging

I can't start session, even  this code run correctly in other website's but in the website i build now it won't work. This is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])&& isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9\@\-\_\|\,\.\\p{L}\\\\]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);// filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the Mysql database
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($r);

    if($userCount == 1 ) {

            while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

                $id = $user['id'];
                $pass = $user['password'];  
                $us = $user['username'];

            }

            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["manager"] = $us;
            $_SESSION["password"] = $pass;
            header("location:index.php?page=business");
            exit(); 

    } else { 
        echo 'That information is incorrect,try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    }   

}
```

until this part of code

```
$id = $user['id'];
$pass = $user['password'];  
$us = $user['username'];
```

everything works fine, but after I set the session variables:

```
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["manager"] = $us;
$_SESSION["password"] = $pass;
header("location:index.php?page=business");
exit();
```

no session found, can any one help me?

Comment: Have you added `session_start()` on top of your PHP codes ?

Comment: did you put session_start() in that page before setting sesions

Comment: You need to add session_start() on both the script

Comment: no i didn't, i forget

Comment: i'm so sorry guy's, i don't know how i forgot that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use the session start, like this:

```
session_cache_expire(20);
        session_start(); 
        session_unregister($username_session);
        session_register($username_session);

$_SESSION[$start_session] = time();
        $validation = true;
        $_SESSION[$username_session] = $user;
```

All my websites, I use this code for login, you can try to use on your login!

```
if ($_POST['btnLogin']) {

$texto = mysql_query("SELECT user, password from " . $site . "User");


$user = $_POST["user"];
$pwd = md5($_POST["pwd"]);

$users = array();
$pwds = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($texto)) {
    array_push($users, $row['user']);
    array_push($pwds, $row['password']);
}
$size = count($users);
$validation = false;
$i = 0;
do {
    if ($user == $users[$i] && $pwd == $pwds[$i]) {
        session_cache_expire(20);
        session_start(); // NEVER FORGET TO START THE <strong class="highlight">SESSION</strong>!!!
        session_unregister($username_session);
        session_register($username_session);
        $inactive = 1200;
        if (isset($_SESSION[$start_session])) {
            $session_life = time() - $_SESSION[$start_session];
            if ($session_life > $inactive) {
                header("Location: login.php");
            }
        }
        $_SESSION[$start_session] = time();
        $validation = true;
        $_SESSION[$username_session] = $user;

        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $i++;
} while ($i < $size && $validation == false);
if ($validation == false) {
    $mensagemerro = 'Login Error!';
}
if (!mysql_close($conn)) {
    die('Could not close BD:' . mysql_error());
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you have meant to post this elsewhere?
Edit: This doesn't address the original question about using sessions.

Comment: This is a similar code that I use! I check user and password on mysql database. If positive, I enter in index.php. If not, I print a error message. Also use sessions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using sessions in PHP, [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/session_start) is required before you can access the $_SESSION global.

Are you using this function? If not, drop it in and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to use a SESSION variable then it means that You are going to start or resume a SESSION.

so in order to start or resume a SESSION  use `session_start()` before the process